# Impossible to access an attribute ("created_at") on a boolean variable ("1")

Tags: createcommand

I have read a number of related threads but am still puzzled what this error actually means or how to fix it.

This triggers the error:

```
<div class="twitter">

                {% set tweets = craft.twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', {count:2}) %}

               {% if tweets %}
                 <h3 class="title">Latest Tweets</h3>
                 <div class="line-orange-l"></div>



                  <ul>
                    {% for tweet in tweets %}
                    {% set tweetDate = date(tweet.created_at).diff(now).format('%a') %}
                    {% if tweetDate == 0 %}
                    {% set tweetTimeAgo = 'today' %}
                    {% else %}
                    {% set tweetTimeAgo = tweetDate ~ ' days ago' %}
                    {% endif %}
                    <li>
                       <p>
                          <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                          {{ tweet.text|autoLinkTweet }}<br>
                          <a href="http://twitter.com/{{ tweet.user.screen_name|raw }}" class="author">@{{ tweet.user.screen_name|raw }}</a> /
                          <span class="posted">Posted {{ tweetTimeAgo }}</span>
                       </p>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </ul>
                  {% endif %}
                 </ul>
              </div>
```

What would fix this?

Comment: A good fix would be defensive coding and checking if the variables exist https://nystudio107.com/blog/handling-errors-gracefully-in-craft-cms#defensive-coding-in-twig

Comment: Thank you, Robin. I was not aware of the Twig ?? null coa­lesc­ing oper­a­tor, which makes total sense to incorporate as a standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error basically means that you're trying to use the variable `tweet` as an object/iterable, but it's actually just a boolean (true/false).

Assuming the plugin you're using (i.e. `craft.twitter`) is [Dukt's Twitter plugin](https://github.com/dukt/twitter), I think this is just a matter of your syntax being a bit off. The Dukt plugin's `craft.twitter.get()` method actually returns a response object where the 
tweet objects are *nested* in an array called `data`. In other words, you can't loop on the object returned by `craft.twitter.get()` directly; you'll need to use the array in that object's `data` property:

```
{% set response = craft.twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', {count:2}) %}

{% if response.success %}
    {% set tweets = response.data %}
    {% for tweet in tweets %}
        {% set tweetDate = date(tweet.created_at).diff(now).format('%a') %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>An error occured:</p>
    <pre>{{ response.data|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT')) }}</pre>
{% endif %}
```

The above example is lifted from [the plugin's documentation](https://docs.dukt.net/twitter/v2/craft-twitter.html#get-uri-query-headers-options-enablecache-cacheexpire) (although in the actual docs there's a typo, which could well be the cause for your issue). Note that the example also accounts for Things Going Wrong (tm), which is always a good idea when you're working with a third party API.

If the plugin you're using is *not* Dukt's, you'll need to check your plugin's documentation, to verify you're using it correctly. As a debugging effort, you might also want to try and [`dump()`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) the response object variable to verify that it contains what you think it contains:

```
{% set tweets = craft.twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', {count:2}) %}
{{ dump(tweets) }}
```

*Note that the `dump()` method only works when [`devMode`](https://craftcms.com/support/dev-mode) is set to `true`, and should not be left in production code.*

Comment: Thank you, Mats for providing clarity and outcome! I did use Dukt's Twitter example and could not figure out the error - the typo explains it....